# What private fields does java have?

Tags: java, string

I'm working on a project that uses ASM-5 to read class files and generate UML diagrams. I've run into an issue in testing to see if we've read correctly.

I’m testing this on the String class. The only field that shows up in the documentation is CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER. This already seemed fishy, but I wrote my tests to check if that field and only that field was read, and turned up with 5 fields: value : char[], hash : int, serialVersionUID : long, serialPersistentField : ObjectStreamField, and CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER : Comparator.

Where did these 4 extra fields come from and why aren't they in the oracle documentation? I also could not access them when I tried to use refection to look at what fields the string class had (I could only see CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER). This seems like something that should be more well documented.

Comment: Why would `private` fields be in the documentation? They are implementation details, not part of the API.

Comment: Documentation is for how you use a class, so you don't include private fields there.  If you want to know about implementation details, you can look at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java?av=f).

Comment: See also: [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 (it's different in other versions), `String` has the following fields (aligned for your convenience):

```
public  static final Comparator<String>  CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER;
private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
private static final long                serialVersionUID;

private       int    hash;
private final char[] value;
```

As you can see, only one of them is `public`, and 3 of them are `static`.

Depending on what you want the UML diagram to show, you need to find the `private` fields too, and you may want to exclude the `static` fields.

Actually, good programming practices means that you'll never find a `public`, non-`static` field.

Comment: Of those variables:  Two of the static variables are for serialization. One of the static variables is the Comparator for `.equalsIgnoreCase`.  One of the variables is the hashcode for `.getHashCode`.  One of those variables is the backing array for the actual `String`.